# In app purchase for auto-renewable content prompts user to share information

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am adding the ability to purchase auto-renewable content through the iOS SDK's StoreKit API.

When testing this in the sandbox on my iOS device, the following message appears in an alert after agreeing to purchase:

> Share your Information? 
>   The publisher of [app name here] would like
>   your name, email, and zip code for use in accordance with their
>   privacy policy.

With buttons for "Don't Allow" and "Allow"

I don't want / need this information and don't want to annoy my users by prompting for it. However, I can't figure out how to disable this prompt to collect private information.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: I've asked the same question on the Apple developer forums with no response. I don't think there's a way to avoid it.

Comment: Marco Armant has a nice write-up on this whole crazy auto-renewable IAP thing. I highly suggest taking a look before you spend any time trying to implement this purchase option, since Apple will most likely reject your App. http://www.marco.org/2012/01/06/autorenewable-subscription-restrictions

Answer (score 5):

This is a marketing opt-in in your in-app product! Just uncheck it! This should do the trick!

EDIT:

This option is in the iTunesConnect: Select your app in iTunesConnect, select "Manage In-App Purchases" (if you can't see it, you will have to subscribe for it in iTunesConnect > see Contracts). 
Select your autorenewable product and than the duration, you have already registered (e.g: 1 month). There you'll see the option "Offer a marketing opt-in incentive?". Select the option "No". After Apple has verified the product, the option should have gone when a user buys the autorenewable product.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't remember seeing a checkbox. Just an "allow" and "don't allow" button.

Comment: You are right, its an option! But you should also be albe to switch the option in "Offer a Marketing opt-in incentive?" to "No" event though its already on the market.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry i didn't understand your comment correctly. You can see this option in the iTunesConnect > Go to your App > Select your In-App Purchase Product (should be an autorenewable product) > Select the duration (e.g: 1 month) > Select the option "No" in the row "Offer a marketing opt-in incentive?"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying with your edit. What a B.S. interface choice that is on Apple's part.

Comment: That doesn't remove the alert. The "incentive" means that they'll give users their first subscription period free if they opt to share their information.

Comment: @chrispix: I'm not quite sure, what you mean. Do you mean that your alertbox isn't being removed directly after you unchecked the market-opt in? If so, just wait until your autornewable got proved by appel. Please let me know, what issues you have in detail, or if it helped.

Comment: It seems that for free subscriptions there's no way to remove the opt-in message though: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases_Robert/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH4-SW9 "Note that Free Subscriptions can’t offer a marketing opt-in incentive (since the subscription is already free), but users will still be asked if they want to opt-in to share their information."

Comment: My company's app has several paid auto-renewing subscriptions with the "Offer a marketing opt-in incentive?" option set to No. We are still seeing the "Share Your Information?" dialog. Would very much prefer to find a way to turn it off.

Comment: afaik, there is no way to turn it off - it's something that we have to suffer I guess :/

Comment: I've noticed this problem in the past too. It seems, that when you test those opt ins and try to turn it off for the specific product, it doesn't really do what yout want the system to do.

Comment: Im my understanding, turning off "Offer a marketing opt-in incentive" should do the trick. Here is the direct link to the Chapter "Using Incentives to Sell Subscriptions" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW16
Just for completeness.

Comment: Hey, i turned off, Offer a marketing opt-in incentive?", so when my app in live,  won't come, "share information" prompt ?

Comment: I didn't find the option to disable this in the iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no option to disable this prompt.

Comment: Is there any documentation around this?

Comment: I have not seen any documentation around being able to remove the prompt, no.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer from apple: *"You need to send a request to App Review and they can disable this feature. You can contact App Review using the email address appreview@apple.com."*

Comment: you go this answer in private emailing or somewhere on forum/official docs/any public sources?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an official [answer from Apple Staff](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14985)

> The "Share Your Information" dialog can be disabled by App Review.
>   Please submit a request to appreview@apple.com, provide the
>   application ID with the request. App Review may ask for additional
>   information, but they can change the setting which triggers the
>   presentation of this alert to users.
>
> You may be aware of the option for Auto Renewing subscriptions to
>   "Offer a marketing opt-in incentives" - yes/no. This setting controls
>   whether the user will be provided a bonus free period for sharing
>   their information. This option does not control whether the "Share
>   Your Information" alert is presented.