# In app purchase for Free Subscription prompts user to share information

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, newsstand-kit

I am working on NewsStand application where user can get free Subscription through the iOS SDK's StoreKit API.

When testing this in the sandbox on my iOS device, the following message appears in an alert after agreeing to purchase:

> Share your Information? The publisher of [app name here] would like your name, email, and zip code for use in accordance with their privacy policy.
>
> With buttons for "Don't Allow" and "Allow"

I know how to tuned off in auto-renewable subscription. The option will come in Add duration and pricing "Offer a marketing opt-in incentive?". But I can't figure out how to disable this prompt for free Subscription.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you are right about turning off in auto-renewable subscription by toggling "Offer a marketing opt-in incentive?".

As much as I can remember there is no way to avoid this option (from marketing point and Apple this is a feature). Either user trusts you and he/she would allow it or he/she would not. Nothing too serious or critical about this, they've already done with the subscription part and have your magazine/newspaper. The only possible problem there is if someone wants to read your privacy policy so you should be sure it's accessible and updated. (but totally agree if you don't want this information, no point to bring it up to the users!)

There is something similar here, but you see 1 says it is possible 1 say no.

[In app purchase for auto-renewable content prompts user to share information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578115/in-app-purchase-for-auto-renewable-content-prompts-user-to-share-information)

Edit: Well it seems it is possible to do what you said in auto-renewal subscription but in the meantime here one of the comments:

> it seems that for free subscriptions there's no way to remove the
>   opt-in message though: developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/…
>   "Note that Free Subscriptions can’t offer a marketing opt-in incentive
>   (since the subscription is already free), but users will still be
>   asked if they want to opt-in to share their information."

– Gustavo Ambrozio

same problem here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595779/in-app-purchase-disabling-marketing-opt-in-incentive